# Nhibernate ver. 1, command-timeout not working

Tags: nhibernate, ado.net, castle-windsor

We are using Castle Windsor with Nhibernate and we are having issues with command-timeouts. Basically this should be a straight forward issue to resolve but somehow Nhibernate ignores the property from the configuration file.

This is the Nhibernate configuration:

```
<factory id="nhibernate.factory">
            <settings>
                <item key="hibernate.command_timeout">3000</item>
                <item key="hibernate.show_sql">false</item>
                <item key="hibernate.connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</item>
                <item key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</item>
                <item key="hibernate.connection.connection_string">#{coreDevConnectionString}</item>
                <item key="hibernate.dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2000Dialect</item>
                <!--<item key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</item>-->
            </settings>
            <assemblies>
                <assembly>Midas.Persistence</assembly>
                <assembly>Midas.DbiCore</assembly>
            </assemblies
```

The timeouts is only 30 seconds. Here is a code example used:

```
Dim session As ISession = sessionManager.OpenSession()
Dim result As T
result = CType(session.Load(GetType(T), id), T)
session.Close()
setDirty(Of T)(result, False)
Return (result)
```

I have tried to set the property "hibernate.command_timeout" and "command_timeout" as well both nothing seems to be working.

I am getting an Nhibernate.AdoException which contains the following error message:

*Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.*

Here is the StackTrace:
*System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at Midas.Persistence.ScoreInformationMapper.Calculate(Int64 companyID, Int64 ModelID, Boolean ForceRecalculate, String& errorMessage, User user, InformationSource informationSource) at Midas.BusinessLogic.ScoreInformationController.CalculateScore2017(Int32 companyId, Int32 modelId, Boolean ForceRecalculate, User user, InformationSource informationSource) at Midas.BusinessLogic.ScoreInformationController.ReCalculateScore(ScoreInformation scoreInformation, User user, InformationSource informationSource, Boolean ForceCalculation, Boolean useRaiseEvent) at Midas.BusinessLogic.ScoreInformationController.AnyInformationUpdated(Object modifiedInformation, CompanyId companyId, User user, InformationSource informationSource) at Midas.BusinessLogic.ScoreInformationController.OwnershipInformationUpdated(Object sender, InstancePersistedEventArgs`1 e) at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e) at Midas.BusinessLogic.OwnershipInformationController.Save(OwnershipInformation instance, User user, InformationSource informationSource) at Midas.Import.RegtidEjerregisterImportController.ProcessRow(DataRow[] sourceRows, User user, InformationSource informationSource, IImportMessageBuilder importMessageBuilder) at Midas.Import.ImportManager.ExecuteImport(IRowImportController rowImportController, SourceDataProviderConfig sourceDataProviderConfig, String informationSourceShortName)*

Comment: *Is* the server able to respond? Can you connect to it from SSMS? 30 seconds is a lot. What is the **full** exception, including its call stack? You can get this with `Exception.ToString()`. This will show whether this was caused by a connection timeout (meaning you can't connect to the server at all). A command timeout would mean that the query is very expensive. 30 seconds for an ORM query is *way* too long.

Comment: The reason for the timeout is because of locks. The stacktrace clearly indicates a timeout and not a connection timeout.

Comment: *Post* it here, don't read it aloud. In any case, if the problem is locks, you should fix your query, not cover it up with a larger timeout. *Why* is it slow? What is the execution plan? What is the actual query? Are there any missing indexes? You can get 300x (not 300%, 300%) times better performance with the proper index

Comment: If the query is good but processes a lot of data you are using the wrong tool altogether. **All** ORMs, not just NH are unsuitable for reporting queries. There are no entities with behaviour to return and map to, just DTOs. The queries they generate are *not* going to perform well in such cases. When you have a lot of data, you want to stream it, not munch it all in one go.

Comment: I have added the StackTrace. I will have a look at the indexes.

Comment: What is `Midas.Persistence.ScoreInformationMapper.Calculate` and why does it call `ExecuteNonQuery` directly? This doesn't go through NHibernate. Set the command timeout on the connection string used by that method. And post the *full, relevant code* and exception string *without* breaking its formatting next time. The exception string is already indented

Comment: PS you can set the command timeout on the command object itself through the [SqlCommand.CommandTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx) property

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the timeout in the connection string
https://www.connectionstrings.com/all-sql-server-connection-string-keywords/

Comment: It is not the connection timeout, but the command timeout. But thanks for the tip.